# Issue with CInt - "When casting from a number, the number must be less than infinity"

Tags: vb.net, casting

When passing a value from the string variable `placevalue1` to integer variable `pv1` I am getting the error "`When casting from a number, the number must be less than infinity`".

Everything I have found and tried hasn't solved my problem.

```
Sub converttobinary1()
    Console.WriteLine(bit)
    Dim placevalue1, placevalue2, placevalue3, placevalue4, placevalue5, placevalue6, placevalue7, placevalue8 As String
    Dim pv1, pv2, pv3, pv4, pv5, pv6, pv7, pv8 As Integer

    'Convert.ToInt32(bit)
    placevalue1 = Mid(bit, 8, 1)
    pv1 = (CInt(placevalue1)) * 1 'I've tried this......
    'pv1 = placevalue1 * 1
    placevalue2 = Mid(bit, 7, 1)
    pv2 = CInt(placevalue2)      'and this......
    'pv2 = placevalue1 * 2
    placevalue3 = Mid(bit, 6, 1)
    pv3 = CInt(placevalue3)
    'pv3 = placevalue1 * 4
    placevalue4 = Mid(bit, 5, 1)
    pv4 = CInt(placevalue4)
    'pv4 = placevalue1 * 8
    placevalue5 = Mid(bit, 4, 1)
    pv5 = CInt(placevalue5)
    'pv5 = placevalue1 * 16
    placevalue6 = Mid(bit, 3, 1)
    pv6 = CInt(placevalue6)
    'pv6 = placevalue1 * 32
    placevalue7 = Mid(bit, 2, 1)
    pv7 = CInt(placevalue7)
    'pv7 = placevalue1 * 64
    placevalue8 = Mid(bit, 1, 1)
    pv8 = CInt(placevalue8)
    'pv8 = placevalue1 * 128
    'Console.WriteLine(bit)
    denary = placevalue1 + placevalue2 + placevalue3 + placevalue4 + placevalue5 + placevalue6 + placevalue7 + placevalue8

    Console.WriteLine("The binary number you entered, " & bit & " is " & denary & " in denary (or Base 10)")

    ' Console.WriteLine(denary)
    ' Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a **minimal**, **complete** program with appropriate input that exhibits this behaviour. The code you’ve posted doesn’t help in solving the problem. However, as an aside, you should avoid the legacy VB6 functions (such as `Mid`) and use .NET framework functions (such as `String.Substring`) instead. And don’t use numbered variables – use arrays instead.

Comment: what is the value of bit?

Comment: char is 2 bytes in ASCII. the numerical symbol 1 is 31 (Hex) 0011 0001 (binary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but I think you are making this way too complicated. You can use [Convert.ToInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert between bases in .NET:

```
    Dim s As String = "11111111"
    Dim denary As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(s, 2)
    Debug.Write("The binary number you entered, " & s & " is " & denary & " in denary (or Base 10)")
```

output

```
The binary number you entered, 11111111 is 255 in denary (or Base 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `bit` variable is not initialized. Try to assign a value

```
    Dim bit As Integer = 111111111

    placevalue1 = Mid(bit, 8, 1)
    pv1 = CInt(placevalue1)
```

Comment: `bit` must be a string.

Comment: @KonradRudolph should be a string. `bit` will be converted implicitly to string by `Mid()`. After executing `placevalue1 = Mid(bit, 8, 1)` placevalue1 content is "1" (as string)